# React Navigation Not return to login screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I don't want to go back to my login screen when I log in successfully. When you click the "back" button on your Android devices, the login screen is coming. I Don't want this.

I use;

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Screen 2',
    headerLeft: null        
}
```

It's just hiding the button. For Android devices does not disable the back key. Offer a solution to this. Lead me on this. Don't let the back key work for just one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#docsNav) which will works perfectly for session handling.

Comment: We're talking about the same thing. I use this. Give me my question, please.

Comment: Do u mean it should not work for that particular one screen.

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: Try to use [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I tried that. But it works for all pages.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1819)